# Do I need to get "Always" authorization for background location updates?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm creating an app that uses location services. I need to provide our backend with continues location updates (even when the app is in the background). For this case I have enabled Location Updates Background Mode.

Now my problem is I'm not 100% sure what authorization is required for this.

Do I need to ask for "Always" or is it enough to get "When in use" authorization from the user to be able to process location updates in the background.
I'm not interested in starting the app, on location updates, if it has been terminated (ex. significant location change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your needs. If you need the location to be fetched when the app is in not-running state (that is, when the user switched on the device without opening your app, or if the user has terminated your app), you need "Always" authorisation. If not, then you only need "When in use" authorisation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use "Always" in your case when you want the location update while app is in background or not running, according to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services)